# Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 127 , when i run flutter for the first time

Tags: android, ios, flutter, visual-studio-code

I am having an issue running flutter. Once I run flutter it shows the following error on visual code, any solution to this. I run flutter doctor, don't know if the issue is from the details.

````
Using hardware rendering with device sdk gphone x86. If you notice graphics artifacts, consider enabling
software rendering with "--enable-software-rendering".
Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...
**env: bash\r: No such file or directory**                               
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                                  
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                         2.9s
*Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 127*```


Just in case you need the Flutter Doctor here is it:

```Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.4, on macOS 11.0.1 20B50 darwin-x64, locale en-GB)
 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
[✗] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    ✗ Xcode installation is incomplete; a full installation is necessary for iOS development.
      Download at: https://developer.apple.com/xcode/download/
      Or install Xcode via the App Store.
      Once installed, run:
        sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
        sudo xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch
    ✗ CocoaPods not installed.
        CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin code that responds to your
        plugin usage on the Dart side.
        Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
        For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
      To install:
        sudo gem install cocoapods
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[!] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2019.1)
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[✓] VS Code (version 1.54.1)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.```
````

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by this line

```sh
**env: bash\r: No such file or directory**
```

You seem to have downloaded the Windows binaries of Flutter but you are using macOS. You should download the correct binaries and re-install Flutter. Take a look here for more information: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27076#issuecomment-487300955

Answer (score -1):

Have you downloaded the flutter and dart plugin in the VS code?
Once follow through the steps mentioned in this website article
https://giancarlocode.com/flutter-tutorials/how-to-install-flutter-on-windows-10-on-visual-studio-code-and-android-studio/